# Copy to AppX output directory with Visual Studio 2013 (WinRT app)?

Tags: dll, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2013

I have a WinRT app built with VS2013 using C#.  It uses SQLite so it needs the **sqlite3.dll** included in the project to be in the output directory.  I included that DLL in my project and set it to *always* copy to the output directory.  The problem is VS2013 copies it to the Debug directory, but not the **AppX** directory underneath **Debug**, which appears to be the WinRT output directory.  Because of the the app fails because it can't find sqlite3.dll, which is up in the parent **Debug** directory instead of the **AppX** directory.

For now I'm just hand-copying the DLL into the **AppX** directory.  What's the best way to fix this problem so that the DLL is copied to the correct directory?

Answer (score 2):

In your project's Properties window choose Build Events tab. On Post-build window include similar string (please, mind to change the path to sqlite3.dll):

```
xcopy /Y $(ProjectDir)3DParties\sqlite3\$(PlatformName)\sqlite3.dll $(TargetDir)AppX\
```

Or even better option. This page https://www.sqlite.org/download.html contains section named "Precompiled Binaries for Windows Runtime" where you can download VSIX package. When you install this package into your system, you can simply reference sqlite3.dll for all target platforms (ARM, x86, x64) including all necessities automatically like this: Add Reference -> Windows 8.1 -> Extensions -> SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1)

Comment: (Tested on VS 2019) When you build for the first time or after removing the AppX folder, this is not working: After the build the DLLs will be in AppX but when you run the app, the AppX deployment will remove the files

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure this is the "right" solution, but I set the file's property to `Content/Copy-if-newer`.

THEN what I've found is that if the `AppX` directory is already there, VS doesn't update it, just as you describe above, BUT if you *delete* the `Appx` directory then VS will create it from scratch and add the necessary files.

Not as good as having everything automated, but beats hand-copying.